# How to get data from nested objects in the form of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

As you can see, the keys are now the name of the items and the corresponding value is another object consisting of two keys - quantity and price.

```
    var itemsToBuy = {
    milk: {
        quantity : 5,
        price: 20
    },
    bread: {
        quantity : 2,
        price: 15
    },
    potato: {
        quantity : 3,
        price: 10
    }
}
```

I tried but I am getting only undefined output.
Want to get data such like :

```
['milk', 'bread', 'potato']

[20, 15, 10]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution

- With `Object.keys()` you can get the keys of your Object as an array. **->** `['milk', 'bread', 'potato']`
- With `Object.entries()` in combination with `map()` you can get the values of the price property as an array. **->** `[20, 15, 10]`

**Example:**

```js
     var itemsToBuy = {
        milk: {
            quantity : 5,
            price: 20
        },
        bread: {
            quantity : 2,
            price: 15
        },
        potato: {
            quantity : 3,
            price: 10
        }
    }
    const keys = Object.keys(itemsToBuy);
    const val = Object.entries(itemsToBuy).map((element)=> element[1].price)

    console.log(keys);
    console.log(val);
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
const object1  = {
  milk: {
      quantity : 5,
      price: 20
  },
  bread: {
      quantity : 2,
      price: 15
  },
  potato: {
      quantity : 3,
      price: 10
  }
}
console.log(Object.entries(object1).map(([key,value])=> value.price))
```

Answer (score 2):

for names:

```
Object.keys(itemsToBuy) //["milk", "bread", "potato"]
```

and for prices:

```
Object.entries(itemsToBuy).map((el)=> el[1].price)//[20, 15, 10]
```

Answer (score 2):

To get object keys you can use: Object.keys()

```
let keys = Object.keys(itemsToBuy) // ["milk", "bread", "potato"]
```

And for the nested values you can get 1st all values

```
let values = Object.values(itemsToBuy) // [{quantity : 5, price: 20}, {quantity : 2, price: 15}, {quantity : 3, price: 10}]
```

And then map to return the new array with elements you want to extract ex.price:

```
let price = values.map(value => value.price) // [20, 15, 10]
```